# In-app database or online database?

Tags: android, database

I'm relatively new in Android development and I'd like to know if it's possible or there's a way to create something like this: access an online database (where I can save, for example, a list of animals via ListView), and each animal has got a property (color, size, age...) which values can be modified. The user would be able to pick an animal of the list and then edit the value of each one of its properties via EditText (and, of course, save it in the database, via button or whatever).

I have never worked with databases, and I don't know if it's better to create something like this using an "online database" or an "in-app database" (I mean aspects of ease and speed of programming, memmory usage and data access for the user)

I ask this before start programming, since we all know what it's like to undo work that has taken to us many hours.

Any ideas would be of great help to guide me, any tutorial or videos too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the database.
If it contains only 100 animaly with a few attributes, an in-app (local) database would be better because it is safe an easier to access. If the database is getting to big and contains several GB of content, an only databse would be recommended.
So you have to know how many information your database shell hold :)

I hope this helps a bit

John

Comment: Thank you for your response, John. You're right, if the content of the database is small, a local db would be better. But I think I'd use a big size of content, so.. I understand that it would be better to use an online database, right?

Comment: Correct. You will need a server then and learn to exchange information between the server and the app. I will have to learn it as well for my project :D I will try to work with this link http://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html Maybe it will help you.